# Why does defining a method at the top level affect other user-defined classes?

Tags: ruby

If I define a top level method like this:

```
def inspect(x)
  # do something useful...
end
```

Then calling `#inspect` on a user-defined class stops working:

```
class Foo; end
p Foo.new # `inspect': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

However, it keeps working for classes like `NilClass` and `String`:

```
p nil    # prints 'nil'
p "test" # prints '"test"'
```

I thought that one explanation for this behaviour could be that top-level execution may be in the `Object` class itself, but it turns out that it's in an instance of `Object` called `main`. Doesn't this mean that methods defined here shouldn't affect other classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main` is a special place. Any methods defined there are defined as private instance methods of Object. This is so you can define pseudo-functions that can be called in any context without an explicit receiver.